# с++ Sfml визуальная настройка положения игровых объектов/кнопок

Tags: c++, разработка-игр, sfml

Как можно визуально как конструктор (типо вин формы в c# или wpf) собрать уровень для игры поставить монстров разместить для UI кнопки,а не прописывать наугад координаты из кода и как потом все объекты соотнести с кодом.

Comment: Вам нужно написать свой редактор.

Comment: @MaximTimakov тоесть уже готовых нету?Либо делать свой либо ставь координаты наугад?

Comment: Так как формат карты у вас скорее всего свой то и писать редактор нужно самому. Либо брать редактор от какого нибудь движка и писать к нему плагин экспорта. Ну либо наоборот - написать импорт из готового редактора.

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/148653/ как вариант